# Earth Engine: Error: Image.select: Pattern 'test' did not match any bands

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to combine two images one containing various bands of the sentinel 2 mission and the other one is created from a feature collection containing two types of polygons that have the values "test" of 0 and 1 as can be seen here:

[image: Polygons converted to map]

The combined image should then be exported following the tutorial here (https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=FyRpvwENxE-A)

Here is my code:

```
RESPONSE = 'test'

trainingMap = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/xxx')
trainingMapReduced = trainingMap.reduceToImage([RESPONSE], 'max');

# combine the images
featureStack = ee.Image.cat([
  image.select(BANDS),
  trainingMapReduced.select([RESPONSE])
]).float()

# consider a kernel of KERNEL_SIZE x KERNEL_SIZE around each pixel
list = ee.List.repeat(1, KERNEL_SIZE)
lists = ee.List.repeat(list, KERNEL_SIZE)
kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE, lists)

arrays = featureStack.neighborhoodToArray(kernel)

# load training and evaluation areas

trainingPolys = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/trainingRegion')
evalPolys = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/testingRegion')

trainingPolysList = trainingPolys.toList(trainingPolys.size())
evalPolysList = trainingPolys.toList(trainingPolys.size())

# These numbers determined experimentally.
n = 100 # Number of shards in each polygon.
N = 2000 # Total sample size in each polygon.

# Export all the training data (in many pieces), with one task 
# per geometry.
for g in range(trainingPolys.size().getInfo()):
  geomSample = ee.FeatureCollection([])
  for i in range(n):
    sample = arrays.sample(
      region = ee.Feature(trainingPolysList.get(g)).geometry(), 
      scale = 30, 
      numPixels = N / n, # Size of the shard.
      seed = i,
      tileScale = 8
    )
    geomSample = geomSample.merge(sample)

  desc = TRAINING_BASE + '_g' + str(g)
  task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(
    collection = geomSample,
    description = desc, 
    folder = BUCKET, 
    fileNamePrefix = FOLDER + '_' + desc,
    fileFormat = 'TFRecord',
    selectors = BANDS + [RESPONSE]
  )
  task.start()
```

The task starts but it fails with the following error message "Error: Image.select: Pattern 'test' did not match any bands."

When I use

```
featureStack = image.addBands(trainingMapReduced, [RESPONSE])
```

instead of

```
featureStack = ee.Image.cat([
  image.select(BANDS),
  trainingMapReduced.select([RESPONSE])
]).float()
```

I get the error message 
"Error: Image.addBands: Cannot add band 'test' because it doesn't appear in srcImg.
"

The print(trainingMapReduced) looks like this:

ee.Image({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "input": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
        "collection": {
          "type": "Invocation",
          "arguments": {
            "tableId": "users/xxx/xxx"
          },
          "functionName": "Collection.loadTable"
        },
        "properties": [
          "test"
        ],
        "reducer": {
          "type": "Invocation",
          "arguments": {},
          "functionName": "Reducer.max"
        }
      },
      "functionName": "Collection.reduceToImage"
    },
    "bandSelectors": [
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "functionName": "Image.select"
})

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the max reducer renames the bandname to "max"
It had to be renamed again.

```
trainingMap = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/xxx')
trainingMapReduced = trainingMap.reduceToImage([RESPONSE], 'max')
trainingMapReduced = trainingMapReduced.rename(RESPONSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ee.FeatureCollection.reduceToImage() names the bands based on the property/field they were reduced from. My guess is that trainingMapReduced only has one band named 0. Maybe try:

```
  image.select(BANDS),
  trainingMapReduced.select([0])
]).float()
```

You could also just do `print(trainingMapReduced)` to see what the names of the bands are.

Comment: Hi Nick thank you for your reply, I have printed the trainingMapReduced and it does contain "bandSelectors": [ "test" ] as can be seen at the bottom of my question. Its strange the error is only thrown when I start the tasks with (task.start()) and then look at the task status. Before that everything runs without an error.